# Clicking a Button frequently makes Event Binding go Haywire

Tags: jquery

On Button Click, I am changing the selected value of a Radio Button

```
$('#left').click(function(){
    move(-1)
})
$('#right').click(function(){
    move(1)
})


function anim_loop(index) {
    if(index == $elements.length){
        index = 0;
    }
    if(timer){
        $elements.filter('.current').stop(true, true).hide().removeClass('current');
        clearTimeout(timer)
    }
    $radios.eq(index).prop('checked', true);
    $elements.eq(index).stop(true, true).addClass('current').fadeIn(1000, function() {
        var $self = $(this);
        timer = setTimeout(function() {
            $self.fadeOut(1000).removeClass('current');
            anim_loop((index + 1) % $elements.length);
            timer = undefined;
        }, 3000);
    });
}
```

But when I click the 'Right' button too quickly, the entire radio button selection loop goes haywire. What could be the possible fix for it?

http://jsfiddle.net/69nk3/3/

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$('#left').click(function(){
  $(this).clearQueue();
  $('#right').stop().clearQueue();
  move(-1);
})
$('#right').click(function(){
   $(this).clearQueue();
   $('#left').stop().clearQueue();
   move(1);
})
```

Comment: yes it worked. Could you explain what was happening. By the way the same behaviour also occurs if you click the radio buttons randomnly. Any idea how to fix that?

Comment: yes, of course. this is occurred by the rebinding of event listeners. We just clear it from the memory before registering another event. its a good practice to use this before all complicated event listeners. $(this).clearQueue(); If its an animation that you want to stop messing with another use this. $('#animated_element').stop().clearQueue(); inside the beginning of the animation code you are about to animate. So all that #animated_element will be blocked on its way and the current animation will start.